# sails.js update or add new row

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I'm starting a project using sails.js and I'ma bit confused about something.

I have a *structure* like this

```
[
  {
    "logins": {
      "1": {
        "login time": "2016-04-02T11:40:06.731Z"
     }
    }
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "createdAt": "2016-04-02T11:40:06.731Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-02T11:40:06.731Z",
    "id": "56ffaf9692bcf108169ef7c8"
  }
]
```

now when a user logs in again, ideally I want the data to look like this

```
[
  {
    "logins": {
      "1": {
        "login time": "2016-04-01T11:40:06.731Z"
     },
      "2": {
        "login time": "2016-04-02T11:40:06.731Z"
     }
    }
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "createdAt": "2016-04-01T11:40:06.731Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-04-01T11:40:06.731Z",
    "id": "56ffaf9692bcf108169ef7c8"
  }
]
```

However, I cannot for the live of me figure out how to "update" or "insert" a new row under "logins" for my user.

Creating the first record is fine and so far the best I could come up with is reading the current value for logins into a buffer and then re-inserting all the values.

That seems clumsy. Does anyone know if sails has some built in method to support what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your 'Logins' argument to array. Than you can use $push while updating. Waterline support only $set operation, so if you want to do that you need to use .native() like that:

```
Model.native(function(error,collection){
    collection.update(
        {_id:YOURID}, // where condition
        {$push:{logins:new Date()}}, // push new value to array
        {}, // options
        function(error,result){} // callback
    )
})
```

To see what you can do with native, see [Node.js MongoDB Driver API - Collections](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html)